# How to output a "\" to a file without using it as a line end

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to output generated header files with generated defines in them. But as these generated defines are multiline and I need to continue them with "\" I need to find a way to output them to a file. But using

```
std::ofstream Target(PathToTarget);
Target << "Some Output\\n";
```

just outputs

```
Some Output
```

to the target file.
How could I fix this?

Comment: Like this: `"Some Output\\\n"` or better `"Some Output\\" << std::endl`

Comment: The code you give does not output what you claim it outputs. It outputs `Some Output\n`

Comment: @MichaelWalz `std::endl ` has side effect that may not be desirable in the context - it **flushes** the stream

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev good point

Comment: @MichaelWalz `endl` is also for flushing the stream. If you want to print a newline, just print it. If you want to flush (a rare need), then use `std::flush`. In the very rare case where you need both a newline *and* a flush, then use `std::endl`.

Comment: As a side note: Before using `#define` macros, especially multi-lined ones, consider using a function. If a non-template function isn't enough, remember that most issues that are solved by macros may be solved better by template functions.

Answer (score 7):

To print a `\` character you need to escape it. So one `\` turns into `\\`. Adding another escape for the newline character, the string you should print is `\\\n`. So try:

```
std::ofstream Target(PathToTarget);
Target << "Some Output\\\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

It can get cumbersome to escape this stuff, so you can also use this instead:

```
Target << R"(Some Output\)" "\n";
```

This is a raw string literal. You can [find more about it online](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/10/16/cpp-11-raw-strings-literals-tutorial/). The gist of it is that inside a raw string literal, `\` and `"` do not have a special meaning anymore, so you can write more natural-looking text, for example `R"(Enter "on"\"off".)"`.

Comment: Since the OP actually wants a newline after the backslash I think it should be `Target << R"Some Output\" << "\n"`.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi Oops, right. Fixed. (Note that the compiler can concatenate string literals at compile time, no need for `<<`.)